# Why are these promises not resolving?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

Do I need the awaits when inside a `promise.all`? What else can be wrong with this?

```
(async => {
    const result = Promise.all(
        await domainContext.get1(id),
        await domainContext.get2(id)
    ).then(r => r);
})();
```

I'm expecting :

```
result = [get1_value, get2_value]
```

I'm getting :

```
'{}'
```

Comment: How are you testing it? IMHO, the code posted seems to lack an explicit `return result;`

Comment: `Promise.all` expects one iterable as an argument. You are passing two arguments. Did you intend for those to be in a set of `[]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Promise.all` expects an *array* as a single argument, not a list of Promises in its arguments. Also, if you're using `Promise.all`, don't `await` inside - that kind of defeats the purpose, because then you're passing an array of *resolved values* to `Promise.all` rather than passing it an array of *Promises* to wait for. Also, to define an async function with no parameters, you need to add an empty parameter list after the `async`:

```js
const get1 = () => Promise.resolve('get1');
const get2 = () => Promise.resolve('get2');
(async () => {
    const result = await Promise.all([
      get1(),
      get2(),
    ]);
    console.log(result);
})();
```

You could also `await` each item in the `result` array, like this:

```js
const get1 = () => Promise.resolve('get1');
const get2 = () => Promise.resolve('get2');
(async () => {
    const result = [
      await get1(),
      await get2(),
    ];
    console.log(result);
})();
```

which might have been what you were trying to do, but note that this results in each item being requested in *serial*, rather than in parallel.